# API Returns String, Need array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am trying to work with the [ResellersPanel API](http://www.resellerspanel.com/) and I have managed to get this far with my code:

```
$result = file_get_contents("https://api.duoservers.com/?auth_username=store-name&auth_password=PasswordHere&section=datacenters&command=get_datacenters");
var_dump($result);
```

Now for whatever reason, they thought it would be a good idea to return everything as a string rather than json or an array.

I need to know how to convert every result into json or an array. The result of the above code is:

```
string(1468) " 0 0 56000 steadfast shared semidedicated dedicated vps vps_solusvm london shared semidedicated vps vps_solusvm australia sis_group shared semidedicated vps_solusvm telepoint shared semidedicated vps_solusvm ficolo shared semidedicated vps_solusvm 0.027 s 0.019 s 4605066977 "
```

How would I convert a string to json? Thank you.

In the [documentation](https://cp.resellerspanel.com/downloads/ResellersPanelAPI.pdf) it does state that they return an array. So why is it returning a string? I've tried contacting them and they told me to contact a web developer for help.

STILL NO SOLUTION.

Comment: How do you want the converted data to look? What do you need to get out of the string?

Comment: Well, `steadfast` is the data center name and the services it provides is `shared, semidedicated, dedicated, vps, and so on.` So. array(center => steadfast, services => array(shared, semidedicated, dedicated)); In other words, an array. I just don't understand why they would return a string and not json.

Comment: You could first split the array by spaces, remove first 3 values, extract (and remove) the 4th value, remove the numbers at the end (if they don't mean anything and use the remainder as the array of services

Answer (score 0):

You can you the `explode()` function.

```
$result = file_get_contents("https://api.duoservers.com/?auth_username=store-name&auth_password=PasswordHere&section=datacenters&command=get_datacenters");

$result = trim($result);
$plans  = explode(" ", $result);
echo $plans[5]; // steadfast
echo $plans[6]; // shared
```

Comment: This code gives me this as a result `Switch/Sydney,Australia]]> sis_group`

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = file_get_contents("https://api.duoservers.com/?auth_username=store-name&auth_password=PasswordHere&section=datacenters&command=get_datacenters");
$jsonData = json_encode(explode(' ', $result));
```

Comment: Um, I got this when I `print_r()` the jsonData. `["\n\t0<\/command>\n\t0<\/error_code>\n\t56000<\/ttl>\n\t\n\t\t\n\t\t\tsteadfast<\/name>\n\t\t\t<\/description>....`

Comment: Your problem get Solved?

Comment: No, does that look useable to you? no

Comment: Yes for me it is giving an output like:
["0","0","56000","steadfast","shared","semidedicated","dedicated"]

Comment: Good for you. That isn't what it looks like for me. So no, it doesn't work.

Comment: This is what it looks like for me: `string(1790) "["\n\t0<\/command>\n\t0<\/error_code>\n\t56000<\/ttl>\n\t\n\t\t\n\t\t\tsteadfast<\/name>\n\t\t\t<\/description>\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\tshared<\/n0>\n\t\t\t\tsemidedicated<\/n1>\n\t\t\t\tdedicated......`

Comment: If the api returns an array no need to use explode. But then directly use that variable.

Comment: READ my question not just the title!

Answer (score 0):

You can use return_type=serialization and it returns it on PHP serialization which if you are using PHP. it is an array